# Неправильно работает цикл

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

Делаю экран с добавлением `view` элементов. Моя задача: я ввожу в `EditText` количество участников, потом нажимаю на кнопку и  должно создаться столько же `LinearLayout` с определенным наполнением. Сначала у меня работало все хорошо, вроде ничего не трогал, и если ввести в поле количество превышающее уже ныне созданные элементы на два, то создается всего один `LinearLayout` с наполнением, а остальные не создаются. То есть изначально 0 элементов, я ввожу цифру пять,создается один `LinearLayout`, потом нажимаю повторно, опять создается один, так дотягиваю до трех на экране, опять нажимаю на кнопку и создается уже два `LinearLayout`, наконец-то у нас пять элементов. Я пытался это как-то исправить, но плачевно. Вот код:

```
        public class DobActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
int i;
Button button;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
EditText d;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dob);
    button = findViewById(R.id.btnDobu);
    linearLayout  = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    d = findViewById(R.id.edUch);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    d.setSelection(0);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String value= d.getText().toString();
    int finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value);

    do {
        i++;
        LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
         View view = new View(getApplicationContext());
        EditText b = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        EditText b2 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout ln2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout ln3 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 100);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpLine = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);

        lp.topMargin = 30;
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));

        view.setLayoutParams(lpLine);
        b.setLayoutParams(lp);
        b2.setLayoutParams(lp);
        ln.setLayoutParams(lnp);
        ln2.setLayoutParams(lnp);

        ln.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ln2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ln3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        linearLayout.addView(ln3);
        ln3.addView(ln);
        ln.addView(b);
        ln.addView(b2);

        ln3.addView(ln2);
        ln2.addView(view);
    }while(i==finalValue);

}
}
```

Вот `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DobActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/edUch"
            android:background="#333"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDobu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:text="Button" /></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку: сломанный цикл.

Замените `while(i==finalValue)` на `while (i != finalValue)`

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше список, и добавлять их через Adapter? Почитайте про RecyclerView, он не так сложен как может показаться на первый взгляд. И там будет все намного проще.
Вот эта часть кода уйдет в xml:

```
LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
     View view = new View(getApplicationContext());
    EditText b = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    EditText b2 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout ln2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout ln3 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 100);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpLine = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);

    lp.topMargin = 30;
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
     view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));

    view.setLayoutParams(lpLine);
    b.setLayoutParams(lp);
    b2.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ln.setLayoutParams(lnp);
    ln2.setLayoutParams(lnp);

    ln.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    ln2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ln3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

А вот эта в адаптер:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String value= d.getText().toString();
int finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value);

    linearLayout.addView(ln3);
    ln3.addView(ln);
    ln.addView(b);
    ln.addView(b2);

    ln3.addView(ln2);
    ln2.addView(view);
}while(i==finalValue);
}
```

Это будет и аккуратнее и большему научитесь.